# Initial State of RNN

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, weights-initialization

Can I initialize the initial state of my RNN to be non-zero? I have some initial condition of the sequence and I want to use this initial condition as the initial state.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Can I initialize the initial state of my RNN to be non-zero?**  Yes, the initial state / weights of a neural network can be initialized to non-zero values.  In fact, the `trainable weights` can be initialized any way you want.

Exactly how you do this depends on the deep learning package that you are using (if you are using a package).  For example, if you are using Keras/TensorFlow, there is built-in functionality to [initialize layer weights](https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/) and [set model weights](https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/#setweights-method).  Here is a nice article demonstrating how this can be done:  ["How to set custom weights in keras using NumPy array"](https://androidkt.com/set-custom-weights-keras-using-numpy-array/).  The article uses random normal initialization, but you can use your desired initial state / weights.

Comment: I think OP was maybe asking about the initial state, i.e. first hidden state not the initialization of the network. - @wrek?
In that case, here is a related thread that might yield an answer: https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/35465/52211

Comment: yes, the $h_0$, the initial hidden state.